# d3.js mouse drag only working after selecting

Tags: d3.js, mouseevent, draggable

I'm still new to d3.js and I'm having trouble handling the mouse drag event. I have the framework set up to do an x-y plot with a circle that's draggable. I can get it to move the circle when I drag it, but only after I try dragging it once, which inadvertently selects the rest of the window... not quite what I had in mind.

I tried putting the code in jsfiddle, but the mouse interaction doesn't seem to work at all there:

http://jsfiddle.net/noiseinthestreet/jjk9ts10/1/

Here's the code:

```
var canvasWidth = 700, canvasHeight = 700;
var margin = 20;
var innerwidth = canvasWidth - margin*2;
var innerheight = canvasHeight - margin*2;
var xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([-10,10]).range([0+margin,canvasWidth-margin]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([10,-10]).range([0+margin,canvasHeight-margin]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().tickSize(1, 0, 0).scale(xScale).orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().tickSize(1, 0, 0).scale(yScale).orient("left");
var impos = [xScale(5), yScale(5)];
var mousedownFlag=0

var dataArray = [-3, 0, 3];

var canvas = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg").attr("width",canvasWidth).attr("height",canvasHeight); 

canvas.append("g")
    .append("svg:image").attr("width","660").attr("height","660")
    .attr("x", xScale(-10)).attr("y", yScale(10));

canvas.append("g").call(xAxis).attr("transform","translate(0,680)");
canvas.append("g").call(yAxis).attr("transform","translate(20,0)");     

function mouseDrag(d) { 
    var x = d3.event.x, 
        y = d3.event.y;
    if(x>0 && y>0)
        d3.select("circle").attr("cx", x).attr("cy", y);
}

function mouseClick(d) {
    var x = d3.event.x, 
        y = d3.event.y;
    d3.select("circle").attr("cx", x).attr("cy", y);
}

// draggable circle
var circle = canvas.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 30)
    .attr("cy", 30)
    .attr("r", 20)
    .on("click", mouseClick)
    .on("drag", mouseDrag);
```

Still, I'm hoping that the fiddle will be close enough so that someone who actually knows what they're doing (i.e., not me) will be able to quickly point to what I need to change :)

Comment: You may want to use the [drag behavior](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior) instead of native `drag` and `click` events.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pablo Navarro's suggestion, I noodled with d3.behavior.drag() for a few minutes and got it working. Thanks! Here are the relevant code sections that I had to change:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag",function(){d3.select("circle").attr("cx",d3.event.x).attr("cy",d3.event.y);});

...

// draggable circle
var circle = canvas.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 30)
    .attr("cy", 30)
    .attr("r", 20)
    .call(drag);
```